# Can't run a jar-file, built from groovy-code compiled with gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, executable-jar

I'm trying to compile (with gradle) and execute (with the java 1.8 runtime) a small groovy program (see *helloWorld.groovy*, below).

But when I try to invoke it, I get **Error: Could not find or load main class helloWorld**

What am I missing?

---

**compile:**

```
lexu> gradle clean jar
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.555 secs
```

**execute:**

```
lexu> java -jar ./build/libs/helloWorld.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class helloWorld
```

**helloWorld.groovy:**

```
class helloWorld {    
   static void main(String[] args) {
      println('Hello World'); 
   }
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "helloWorld"
archivesBaseName = 'helloWorld';
configurations {provided;  inlib;}
repositories {mavenCentral()}
dependencies {compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'}
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'helloWorld'
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your setup.

1. Not breaking, but worth mentioning here: [Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) states your filenames and classes should be uppercase: **HelloWorld.groovy**
2. `gradle` assumes your source files to be under `src/main/java` or in this case, `src/main/groovy`. You can configure it according to your preferences with [gradle groovy plugin - project layout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html#sec:changing_groovy_project_layout):

---

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/groovy']
        }
    }
}
```

---

3. You need to include all runtime dependencies for `groovy` in your jar-archive. For this, let's use use an extended task called `uberjar`.

---

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "HelloWorld"
archivesBaseName = 'HelloWorld';
configurations {provided;  inlib;}
repositories {mavenCentral()}
dependencies {compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7'}

task uberjar(type: Jar,dependsOn:[':compileJava',':compileGroovy']) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.groovy**:

```
class HelloWorld {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      println('Hello World');
   }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! .. step (2) solved my problem, I created the subdirs and moved the source file .. (1) is good advice that I'll follow (3) wasn't needed, since the groovy-jars are on my classpath! (but then I didn't mention that)